# Stop jquery iteration if the .search method will be equal to -1

Tags: jquery, google-maps, search, iteration, javascript-objects

I built a nice tools in order to find my store on a google maps which iterate every location from a javascript object. I need a "no search result" when my .search function won't find any result. The problem is that my code will iterate with every location anyway, so it will create a multiple text for all of my locations. Is there anyway to fix this problem? Here is it my code:

The javascript:

```
    var output = '<div class="searchresults">';
    $.each(markers, function(key, markers) {    
        output += '<div>';
        output += '<h2>'+ markers.title +'</h2>';
        output += '<div>'+ markers.html +'</div>';
        output += '<div>'+ markers.city +'</div>';
        output += '<div>'+ markers.postalcode +'</div>';
        output += '<div>'+ markers.phone +'</div>';
        output += '</div>';

    });
    output += '</div>';
    $('#legend').html(output);

    $('#geocomplete').keyup(function() {
        var searchField = $('#geocomplete').val();
        var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
        var output = '<div class="searchresults">';
        $.each(markers, function(key, markers) {
            if (markers.city.search(myExp) == -1 && markers.postalcode.search(myExp) == -1) {
                output += ( "<p>No search result</p>" );
            } else {
                output += '<div>';
                output += '<h2>'+ markers.title +'</h2>';
                output += '<div>'+ markers.html +'</div>';
                output += '<div>'+ markers.city +'</div>';
                output += '<div>'+ markers.postalcode +'</div>';
                output += '<div>'+ markers.phone +'</div>';
                output += '</div>';
            }
        });
        output += '</div>';
        $('#legend').html(output);
    });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

and the html:

```
    <div class="container-fluid map">
        <h2>Where To Buy</h2>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Find a Store Near You</legend>
            <form>
                <input id="geocomplete" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Start typing your City or Postal Code to get your Chickapea!" size="60" />
                <input id="find" type="button" value="Find" />
            </form>
        </fieldset>
        <div id="legend"></div>
        <div class="container-fluid" id="map-canvas-two"></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Right, so...  what is it doing now, and what did you want it to do instead?

Comment: I explained in the post, if (markers.city.search(myExp) == -1 && markers.postalcode.search(myExp) == -1) {
    output += ( "<p>No search result</p>" );
   } will output no search result for all my location, but I need that it will output only one result

Comment: and i'm asking because it's unclear. can you explain it in another way maybe?

Comment: Do you want to have a look on it? This is the website: https://choosechickapea.com/shop-chickapea/ . 
Indeed this is the first version, so when the search method won't find anything (-1) on the left it will be output nothing, so my div will be empty.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] **in the question itself** (not just a link to an external site)

Comment: I posted the entire code

Comment: "I posted the entire code" That is the problem. Isolate your issue and post relevant code replicating your issue. Do not copy paste everything you have. If you absolutely have to give a long block of code, create a snippet or jsfiddle that shows your problem instead of giving it as a code. It is very hard to parse through all that code and find a problem, and as such, people become much less likely to help you.

Comment: Sure, but actually before I posted the "interesting part". I'm gonna fix it and underline only the problematic part of the code. I added the link in case anyone want to see my tool in action

Comment: I don't know what was hard to understand in this question guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood your problem, which was Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable.
;)

See my [**CodePen here**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/GqwyQk)

You only need a "flag" to determine if no result was found...
In order to block this "repetitive no result found mention" over loop iterations.

**AND** to place this "no result found" out of the `each()` loop.

Here is the modified code part:

```
$('#geocomplete').keyup(function() {
    var searchField = $('#geocomplete').val();
    var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
    var output = '<div class="searchresults">';

    var flagUnfound = true;
    $.each(markers, function(key, markers) {


        if (markers.city.search(myExp) != -1 || markers.postalcode.search(myExp) != -1) {
          flagUnfound = false;

            output += '<div>';
            output += '<h2>'+ markers.title +'</h2>';
            output += '<div>'+ markers.html +'</div>';
            output += '<div>'+ markers.city +'</div>';
            output += '<div>'+ markers.postalcode +'</div>';
            output += '<div>'+ markers.phone +'</div>';
            output += '</div>';

        }
    });

    if(flagUnfound){
      output += ( '<p>No search result</p>' );
    }
    output += '</div>';
    $('#legend').html(output);
});
```

Try with "L9Y" as postal code in the input.

Comment: It works like a charm! Thank you I was struggling on it!

Comment: Edited again for a perfect "uncriticable" answer. ;)